# Choose between angularFire and angularFireCollection

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Before this, I have tried using `angularFire` and `angularFireCollection` but there is always lack 1 of my approach.

Let say I have a node something like following.
You can see that a `parent` with a `single title` and `multiple childs`

```
{
  "parent": {
   "title": "hello world",
    "childs": {
     "childA": "This is child A",
     "childB": "This is child B"
     }
  }
}
```

What I want to do

1. An implicit data binding over the node
2. listening on `childs` so it won't re-retrieve when there is a change
3. Able to loop sub-node (childs) and retrieve single value `parent.title`

When i use `angularFire` I can't reach `2.`

When I use `angulareFireCollection` I can't reach `1.` and `3.`

I really need some helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple ideas that came to mind. Hope they help.

**Query the title manually and use angularFireCollection for `childs`**

With your current structure, it would probably be easiest to just set the title manually and use angularFireCollection to monitor parent/childs/:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);

// manually update the title
fb.child('parent/title').on('value', function(snap) {
   $scope.title = snap.val();
   // this isn't in angular's apply scope, so force an apply
   $scope.$apply();
});

// track changes to childs    
$scope.childs = angularFireCollection( fb.child('parent/childs') );
```

**Splitting the data paths:**

By splitting your data so that parent and children are in separate paths, you can more easily utilize angularFire and angularFireCollection together:

```
/parents/$parent_id/title
/childs/$parent_id/childA/...
/childs/$parent_id/childB/...
```

Query the parent data with angularFire, query the children with angularFireCollection:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
angularFire( fb.child('parents/'+parentId), $scope, 'parent' );
$scope.children = angularFireCollection( fb.child('childs/'+parentId );
```

Comment: I will use splitting the data paths

Comment: @kato what is angularFireCollection? it still exits? Im facing trouble in Sync data to firebase if I need to look up childs on other path with ids in hand

Comment: The equivalents in the current AngularFire version are `$firebaseArray` (for collections) and $firebaseObject (for key/value pairs)